# How to use same user control with same ID but for different device

Tags: c#, html, user-controls

I have some content, which renders with different design for different devices. So the code looks something like below:

```
<%if(HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent.Contains("Phone")){%>
<div class="design1">
<ABC:ShowSomeContent ID="allContent" runat="server" />
</div>
<% } %>
<%if(!HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent.Contains("Phone")){%>
<div class="design2">
<ABC:ShowSomeContent ID="allContent" runat="server" />
</div>
<% } %>
```

The class and design are just example of showing that I want different things apart from the mentioned user control for different devices. There is a lot of code which appears based on condition. In a nut shell, it's imperative to have two condition based user-control entries.
The error which I get is "The ID 'allContent' is already used by another control." How do I avert this error.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your different designs in a `Panel` control instead of a `<div>` element?

Comment: That's the simplest solution I knew would come. But my code is lot complicated than this. There are many other things which render based on device. I just posted a simplest version of my problem.

Comment: And why would the `Panel` control not work with your code, however complicated? Check your conditions on Page Load, then set the `Panel.Visible` attributes as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting multiple control on the page,I will just let the control to show itself differently based on the UserAgent.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a ternary operator to change the class name. For example

```
<div class='<%= HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent.Contains("Phone").ToString() == "true" ? "design1" : "design2" %>'>
  <ABC:ShowSomeContent ID="allContent" runat="server" />
</div>
```